# will it dual boot in Lenovo ideapad z400 touch and will touchscreen functions work

Tags: lenovo

has anyone tried dual booting Lenovo Z400 touch ideapad with ubuntu 13.04 and what are the bugs

Answer (score 0):

I just did however it would seem that the touch screen does not work for me in 13.04

Comment: and then I suspended the laptop and resumed and now the touch screen does work!! now on to the web cam which is not working everything else seems to work.

Comment: edit: no I am wrong, answer is ok, just question is lacking quality and research.